# Search a CSV-file with python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to search a CSV-File with python2 on the Raspberrry Pi. If the file is not found the program should generate it. How I can search a file and can decide with an if-statment if there is CSV-file or not?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Did you try anything yourself? Python does have great csv support, also csv is basically a txt-file so it shouldn't be hard either way. Read also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `os.path.exists('path/to/csvfile')` will return False if the specified file does nor exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @John Anderson said you can use the `os` module's [os.path](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html).

```
if os.path.exists('path/to/your/csvfile/') is True:
    print("Do something")
```